# Problem with shutdown/restart option

Tags: unity, 13.10, shutdown, restart, logout

Whenever I try to shutdown/restart from the system tab, I am given the option to log out or lock and pressing them does nothing. shutting down from the terminal works fine using commands  like `shutdown -h` and I can shut down through steam big picture.

This problem just turned up out from the blue just a few days ago and I have been looking for a fix, but I have just be going round in cycles.

Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is dconf issue that you have just described.  On your terminal window (ctrl+alt+T) and type this:

```
dconf reset -f "/home/yourusername/"
```

note: must use / in the end of the path

dconf is what holds all of the values and defaults factors for Unity thus, that's what controls the reboot/shutdown buttons.  This function reset all of dcnof and bring default back.  It'd might do the trick in your situation.

Comment: That seems to do nothing, even after doing a restart.